# Why Crocodiles don't eat Hippos?

Tags: zoology

I have been following documentaries about crocodiles and amazingly, crocodiles and hippos apparently seem to live happily in the same pond together without attacking each other.

Why is it so? Like no matter how strong hippo is, its soft skin is no match to the brutal jaws of a crocodile?

Comment: Can a crocodile's jaws actually bite into something the size of a hippo?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Skin**

First, you are being misled by your wrong assumption that hippos have soft skin. Hippos have a 5 cm thick skin! For fun, here is a picture of a hippo skin.

[image]

**They are big and pretty fast**

An adult hippo weighs on average 1.5 and 1.3 tons for males and females respectively (with a record at 4.5 tons) and can run up to 30 km/h on land and up to 8 km/h in water (according to [wikipedia > hippopotamus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippopotamus)).

[image]

**They have an aggressive nature**

Hippos are aggressive animals (esp. males). Hippos kill about 500 people a year (against 1000 for crocodiles) according to [this BBC article](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-36320744) (but estimates seem to vary quite a bit from source to source).

[image]

[image]

**They have serious teeth**

Hippos have a big mouth with very long teeth. Lower canines are 50cm (19.7 inches) long (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippopotamus) citing [Estes 1991](https://books.google.ch/books?id=g977LsZHpcsC&printsec=frontcover&dq=isbn:0520080858&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjW7qm0iLXNAhXCvxQKHfnHDlAQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q&f=false))!

[image]

**Hippos live in herd**

As suggested by @ChinmayKanchi in the comments, because hippos live in a herd, a crocodile that attacks a hippopotamus might have to deal with more than one enemy.

**Videos**

You can find [here](http://channel.nationalgeographic.com/wild/worlds-deadliest/videos/croc-vs-hippo/) a video fight between a crocodile and a hippopotamus (thanks to @TahlaIrfan) and [here](https://rumble.com/v3jtrx-lions-attempt-at-hunting-hippo-backfires-spectacularly.html) is a video of a lion waking up a hippo. You will easily find other videos on YouTube.

Comment: @Remi.b Can you please cite the reference about the speed and weight? Thanks.

Comment: My reference is simply wikipedia (wiki does not give further reference).

Comment: @Remi.B First video link no longer works -- could you find an alternative source? 2nd video link is great :).

Answer (score 6):

They don't look like prey animals. This is one of the most impressive skulls to stand beside of any living animal: [image]
[image]
The skin weighs about 270 kilos for an adult hippo of 1.5 tons, ranging from 12 to 35mm thick. 
[image]
on page 3 https://physoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1113/expphysiol.1964.sp001695

Comment: Hyenas are really badass. I saw a video last week when they killed even a hippo.

Comment: The skin look more than 35 mm thick in your last picture...

Comment: I know, I was puzzled by that so I checked an anatomy document which states 12-35 cm epidermis so presumably it's fat, on the hyperlink.

Answer (score 2):

As Remi.b explained above, the average hippo is just too big and dangerous for the average croc to handle. That said, there were cases that very large crocodiles (such as the [infamous Gustave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gustave_(crocodile))) attacked and ate juvenile hippos (or very old or sick hippos). But usually the two practice a mutual "respect and awe" relationship with tense tolerance to each other, which may turn into a brutal fight if one of the sides gets too close to the other.

Comment: Could you add references to backup your answer?

Comment: For Gustave: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gustave_(crocodile), see also [Google](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=crocodile+eats+hippopotamus&oq=crocodile+eats+hip&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.6872j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)